# how to keep setting after scene change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I have a options menu on 1 scene but when you load into the game (Switch scene) then come back (Switch scene) it loses all the settings. I was trying to do it with DontDestroyOnLoad and could not get it to work an i could not figure out how to read and write a text file. What is the best way to keep all the settings?
Image: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d7dI.png)

Comment: memento pattern???

Comment: I think it would work based off of the wiki article but I am not sure on how to incorporate it into the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unity, you can save and load settings via the [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) class. This is a static class which means you can access settings anywhere in your Unity script files.

Example usage:

```cs
// Set the player name preference
PlayerPrefs.SetString("player_name", "Darian Benam");

// Save all the preferences
PlayerPrefs.Save();

// Load the player name from the preferences
string playerName = PlayerPrefs.GetString("player_name"); // According to this example, the value of the string will be "Darian Benam"
```

Reloading the settings in the menu scene will need to be done in the `Start()` method of your script. You will just need to set the values of your GUI components to the return value of the getter methods in the `PlayerPrefs` class.